# Bounding ceiling functions

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am working on a function which I want to find a nice lower bound for it. The function is
$$
\left(\lceil \frac{x}{2}\rceil-\left|x-2\lceil\frac{x}{2}\rceil\right|\right)^2, \qquad \text{for }x\geq 0
$$
By plotting graph, it turns out that this function can be bounded below by $\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)^2$. However, I have trouble in working this bound analytically. I have been trying to use the inequality $\lceil x\rceil-1<x\leq \lceil x\rceil$, but it is not getting to the result.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you break into cases conditional on whether the fractional part is greater than or less than 1/2? What do you get?

Comment: If $x$ is an even integer, the expression reduces to $\left(\frac x2\right)^2 > \left(\frac {x-1}2\right)^2$, so your upper bound is not correct.

Comment: I suggest you start by simplifying the expression. You can easily remove the absolute value, as the expression inside will always have the same sign (or be $0$). Then you can do more algebraic simplication to get an expression that is easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You function is basically

$$f(x)=(x-n)^2\ \ \text{if}\ \ x\in(2n-2,2n]\ \ \text{for}\ \ n\in\mathbb N^+.$$

To see this, use the facts $\lceil x/2\rceil=n$ for $x\in(2n-2,2n]$ and $|x-2\lceil x/2\rceil|=2\lceil x/2\rceil-x$.

---

To find a lower bound, we need to find the minimum of $f(x)$ on each interval $x\in(2n-2,2n]$, i.e. $\inf_{x\in(2n-2,2n]}f(x)$. Since $f$ is piecewise quadratic, we simply get

- If $n=1$, then $\inf_{x\in(0,2]}f(x)=\inf_{x\in(0,2]}(x-1)^2=0$ when $x=1$,
- If $n\geq2$, then $\inf_{x\in(2n-2,2n]}f(x)=\inf_{x\in(2n-2,2n]}(x-n)^2=(n-2)^2$ when $x=2n-2$.

So the minimum points are $(1,0),(2,0),(4,1),(6,4),...,(2n-2,(n-2)^2),...,$ based on these we can easily find a lower bound $L$ by

$$L(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}(x-1)^2,&0\leq x\leq1\\0,&1<x\leq2\\\frac14(x-2)^2,&x>2\end{matrix}\right..$$

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/orjuhe1ezl) is the Desmos plot for this bound.

---

If you don't want a piecewise bound, simply use $L(x)=\frac{(x-2)^2-2}4$.